# Ember JS - internationalization

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Are there any examples, tutorials on how to use internationalization in Ember JS apps? I found this [ember-i18n add-on](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n), but the docs seem to be outdated and there are no examples in their Wiki. It seems a little bit strange this lack of documentation and resources on ember CLI and Ember JS sites about that compared for example Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I think this plugin provide very good and verbose wiki. I've been using this plugin without any problem.

https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki

Comment: @TalhaJunaid, really ? Sure it works.  The section about Injecting the i18n service in the route fails (at least for ember-cli 2.16.2) as the syntax changed (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/applications/services/). May be that's why I can't make the interpolation work in my templates. Compared to Rails doc it still has a long way to go.

Comment: Yes. I'm also using the same version

Comment: Make it sure to use single quotes for specifying key in interpolation
e.g `{{t 'SomeKey'}}`

Comment: So how to pass in a variable to a translation from a template ? In Rails, we define a translation like that in a YAML file: `failure: "Could not authenticate you from %{kind} because of %{reason}."` And we pass  in the corresponding values like that: `t('.failure', kind: some_variable, reason: another_value)`. I wonder how to achieve the same in Ember ?

Comment: Another question: how to configure the service ? The way dscribed in wi-ki (https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-Setting-the-Locale is not clear enough... I mean what exactley and where should I add ? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could be more precise about what you want to do? What do you want to configure at the service? and if your translation is `"foo": "Hello {{name}}"` you can do `{{t 'foo' name=myNameVar}}`. All in the wiki docs.

Comment: I've implemented a mixin in app to wrap up the plugin.
`export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    i18n: Ember.inject.service(),
    translate(textToTranslate) {
        const i18N = this.get("i18n");
        return i18N.t(textToTranslate);
    }
});
`
then anywhere in the application where you want to dynamically translate the string I just need to import mixin like and use like
`this.translate("translationKey")`

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest: [ember-intl](https://github.com/ember-intl/ember-intl)

Their Readme is very helpful, and it has worked well when I've used it.

Comment: This is what we use. Works well and follows expected patterns for locale files.